# Applications of Vito Volterra's theorem

Tags: analysis, continuity

We know from Volterra's theorem that:

*There cannot exist two pointwise discontinuous functions on an interval $(a,b)$ for which the continuity points of one, are the discontinuity points of the other, and vice versa.*

A well known corollary of this theorem states that there does not exist a function continuous only at the rationals.

So I was wondering whether there are some other examples of this theorem, i.e. whether there are some other complementary dense sets in $\mathbb R$(or any other set) for which this theorem is applicable?